# adjust the resolution of licode platform

Tags: resolution, webrtc, getusermedia, licode

I set up the licode platform by referring [licode documentation](http://lynckia.com/licode/install.html) 
in this platform how can I adjust the resolution of videos (in the basic example). I try to adjust the resolution by ./licode/extras/basic_example/public/script.js file. But I was unable to do it. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by resolution that you mean the input video constraints.

To do this you would specify it when instantiating a stream object. The example below defines a minimum of 640 by 480 pixels, and a maximum of 1280 by 720:

`var stream = {audio: true, video: true, data: true, videoSize: [640, 480, 1280, 720]};`

You can find further documentation on it here: http://lynckia.com/licode/client-api.html#stream

extract: 
You can also specify some constraints about the video size when creating a stream. In order to do this you need to include a videoSize parameter that is an array with the following format: [minWidth, minHeight, maxWidth, maxHeight]